# Pointwise and uniform convergence of series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sin nx}{n^2}$ and $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{x^2+n}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, continuity, uniform-convergence, uniform-continuity

For which domains in R the series of functions $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{\sin nx}{n^2}$ and $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{(-1)^n}{x^2+n}$ converge pointwise and for which domains do they converge uniformly. I'm not sure if they would be different for uniform and pointwise.

Comment: In the first series perhaps it should also be divided by $x^2+n$?

Comment: @H.H.Rugh: My bad, the denominator was $n^2$ not $x^2$

Comment: Ok, when dividing by $n^2$ is it both absolutely and uniformly convergent (since $\sum_n 1/n^2 <+\infty$). Had you only divided by $n$ then it is neither abs nor unif conv (but the latter is a bit more tricky to show).

Answer (score 1):

For the second series $S(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{n+x^2}$, we note that for all $N$, the partial sum $\left|\sum_{n=1}^N (-1)^n\right|$ is bounded by $1$ for all $N$.

Furthermore, we see that $\frac{1}{n+x^2}$ is monotonic and uniformly converges to $0$ since for all $\epsilon >0$, we have

$$\left|\frac{1}{n+x^2}\right|\le \frac1n <\epsilon$$

whenever $n>1/\epsilon$ for all $x$.

Therefore, [Dirichlet's Test for Uniform Convergence](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_Test_for_Uniform_Convergence#Theorem) guarantees that $S(x)$ converges uniformly.  And uniform convergence trivially implies pointwise convergence.

Answer (score 0):

The only case I can find for the first serie converging is if $x = mod(\pi)$.

The second serie $\sum {(-1)^n\over x^2+n}$ is an alternate serie (ie : of the form $\sum (-1)^n a_n$ ) thus is converges if the sequence $1\over x^2+n$ is positive decreasing and its limit is $0$ which is the case $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}$

Comment: How do you arrive to your conclusion for the first series?

Comment: Well the only case I could think of $\sum {sin nx\over x^2}$ converging is when ${sin nx\over x^2} = 0$ which is $x = k\pi, k\in \mathbb{Z}-\{0\}$. We exclude $x=0$ for obvious reasons.